# Does "Full metal jacket" synergize with "Elder Blank"?

Tags: enter-the-gungeon

I just played a few games so I am quite new to the game and am not sure how much I can rely on the Item texts doing exactly what their text says.

So I found in the first level an "Full metal jacket" what is quite an asset for me, as it uses a blank, when ever I would take damage and hence preventing the damage. So far I am on the 2nd floor and made the first floor perfect without getting damage. By now I received no dmg in the 2nd floor but am out of blanks, when I found an "Elder Blank". Its text says it works exactly like an usual blank, but its reusable (reusable by taking up my ability item slot). So I feel like by the wording of these 2 items, the Full metall jacket should trigger my ability item for me aswell, if I should run out of blanks. But I don't want to just try it risking to ruin my master run for the 2nd floor. Nor I want to wait till I figure it out by a given situation, cause I would in case it doesn't synergize prefer keeping my old item with me.

**So can anyone tell me if "Full metal jacket" synergizes with "Elder Blank"?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I just tried it out my self:

It infact synergizes. The ability is automatically triggered to prevent damage if a bullet would hit me. Aditionally the ability was even prefered over the consumable blanks and was used when ever the CD of Elder Blank was up.